# Create an expression based off grouped rows ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I want to create a single rectangle on a report that displays red if there are more then 2 distinct projects being worked on within that week (see image below):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7sFD.jpg

I'd need to write some kind of expression like ***IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Project_Name.Value)> 1, "Red","White")***  but the issue is that I need the projects to be aggregated per user.

As you can see in the above report I have it grouped on User >> Project, and thats what I'd need to captcher in this single expression.

Is there any way to specify a group in an expression?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to do what I wanted via filtering on the tables group, and then hiding all the cells bar one in the table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXCS.jpg

Although if anyone knows a way to group within an expression I would still be interested in knowing.

Thanks